# Wordpress function to add text

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I m using this simple function to add text to my wordpress site post !

```
add_filter( 'afip_new_post_content', 'myprefix_change_afip_post_content', 10, 2 );
/* Grabs the image source for the newly created image and inserts it
* into the new post content along with a one line paragraph. */
function myprefix_change_afip_post_content( $post_content, $attachment_id ) {

$my_uploaded_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );
$post_content = '<p>This is my new uploaded image....</p>';
return $post_content;
```

I'm trying to add the title , the author and the date to

```
$post_content = '<p>This is my new uploaded image....</p>';
```

How do i insert wordpress post title , post author and the date to the above text

Like

```
$post_content = ‘This post – $post_title() ; is uploaded by the_author() on the_time() on category the_category()
```

Comment: Don't use bold sentences unnecessarily the way you did. It is considered shouting, which is bad manners.

Comment: What is `afip_new_post_content`? That is not a Core hook.

Comment: pls find below the link to full code - its for a plugin called automatic-featured-image-posts - http://jeremyfelt.com/wordpress/plugins/automatic-featured-image-posts/

Full source code at -  
http://jeremyfelt.com/wordpress/2012/04/14/filters-in-automatic-featured-image-posts/

Answer (score 0):

As your hook only passes the `$post_content` and `$attachment_id`, you'll first need to get the relevant post, and then you can output your required data.

Please try this and comment if it does not meet your requirements.

```
    function myprefix_change_afip_post_content( $post_content, $attachment_id ) {

            global $post
            $post = get_post( $attachment_id );
            setup_postdata( $post );

            $my_uploaded_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );

            $post_content = sprintf(
                    'This post – %1$s is uploaded by %2$s on %3$s on category %4$s',
                    get_the_title(),
                    get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' );
                    get_the_date(),
                    get_the_category()
            );

            wp_reset_postdata()

            return $post_content;

    }
```

**Note** - this will overwrite the previous `$post_content`. If you want to add to it instead simply replace `$post_content = sprintf(` with `$post_content.= sprintf(`.

Comment: Thanks David for your help...but its not working .. I hope ..you can fix this !
Many Thanks

Comment: Somehow i m able to get this working but its not displaying the category and author name ...  title and Date its working